# If there's === and !== for comparison then why isn't there <== and >==?

Tags: javascript, php

So if PHP and JavaScript's `===` and `!==` perform both identity and value comparison, why aren't there `<==` and `>==` that perform both identity and value comparison as well (less than and greater than - for same types) ???

In JavaScript this `2 <= '2'` always returns `true`. But What if I want both operands to be the same type?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183269/discussion-on-question-by-marvinissacul-if-theres-and-for-comparison-th).